# Laravel 5 unable to generate where conditions in foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to generate where conditions within a foreach loop.

```
$query = \App\Model\ModelName::where('offerId', 3)->where('keyword', 'demo')->get();
$arr = [['setno', '=', '1'], ['deleted', '=', '0']];
$query->where(function($q) use ($arr){
  foreach($arr as $condition){
    $q->where($condition[0], $condition[1]);
  }
}
```

But when I `dd($query);` it show me the below error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'dd' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: `where` can just take that array itself, you dont have to iterate and add the wheres .... `where($arr)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the closing bracket:

```
$query->where(function($q) use ($arr){
  foreach($arr as $condition){
    $q->where($condition[0], $condition[1]);
  }
}); // <-- here
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the closing `);` for the `where` call.

```
$query = \App\Model\ModelName::where('offerId', 3)->where('keyword', 'demo')->get();
$arr = [['setno', '=', '1'], ['deleted', '=', '0']];
$query->where(function($q) use ($arr){
    foreach($arr as $condition){
        $q->where($condition[0], $condition[1]);
    }
});
dd($query);
```